# CSV import checked rows != checked entities

Tags: magento2

**I have a really weird "bug", (I call it like this), while importing products with csv importer controller.**

> Look at this :

1: Begin data validation

2: The validation is complete.

3: Checked rows: **2283**, checked entities: 2283, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 0

4: Import data validation is complete.

1: Begin import of "catalog_product" with "append" behavior

2: Checked rows: 0, checked entities: **500**, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 0

3: The import was successful.

**Any idea what I am doing wrong ?
I look the 500th product it seems well.**

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem here is what I did :
I removed some field of the input.
It was the description attribute who mess up.

There is no reason about it sadly.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same error, i have

Checked rows: 2136, checked entities: 2118, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 0

try leaving the description field empty but not work, any other idea?